# Nginx [emerg] duplicate location when there is no other file containing the statements

Tags: nginx-config

I've included in the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf files the following line to remove from the access log, favicon, php, sitemap messages:

include access_log_rules/log_off.conf;

**log_off.conf file content:**

```
location = /favicon.ico {
log_not_found off;
access_log off;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
access_log off;
log_not_found off;
}

location = /sitemap.xml {
log_not_found off;
access_log off;
}
```

The problem is that I cannot start nginx, I encounter the following error:

> nginx: [emerg] duplicate location "/favicon.ico" in
>   /etc/nginx/access_log_rules/log_off.conf:1

If I search duplicates for that statement, there is none. 
    "grep -rnw '/etc/nginx' -e 'favicon.ico'"

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, there was a duplicate inclusion of the following row in a conf file:

`include access_log_rules/log_off.conf;`